# MYSQL query change column value based on the other column value

Tags: mysql

I have a MySQL query .I want to set column hours=0 when the sub task is 'PTO'.I tried below query but it is not working as expected.

```
 select distinct t.hours, t.subtask,
        CASE sub task
         WHEN 'PTO' THEN t.hours=0
        ELSE t.hours
        END as subtask
    from task t
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try below

```
select distinct t.hours, t.subtask, 
CASE t.subtask WHEN 'PTO' THEN 0 ELSE t.hours END as updated_subtask 
from task t
```